# Is it possible to have a text always perfectly centered while using padding on it?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a simple layout like this :

```
<div class="centered">
<p class="msg">This is an important message</p>
</div>
```

with this style sheet applied on it :

```
.centered {
text-align: center;
}

.msg {
border: 1px solid red;
color: red;
display: inline-block;
padding: 200px;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to apply a padding on the `.msg` class while still keeping the `.msg` text perfectly centered in the body.

As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74rmp75y/) :

With a `padding` of `0`, the text is always perfectly centered.

[padding-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xrR9.png)

If I use a `padding` of i.e `200px`, the centering isn't perfect anymore.

[padding-200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQJE2.png)

**What should I do to keep perfect centering while using padding ?**

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your padding is making the element bigger than the page, that's going to overflow to the right because you can't scroll to negative offsets.

Comment: This behaviour is expected if your `padding` property values are declared with explicit values (`px` rather than `%`). But even with more dynamic values, at some point this issue will become apparent again. You may want to re-evaluate why you are using `padding` and consider if there isn't a better property, or combination of properties, you could be using instead to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of position and transform this way:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, .centered {
  height: 100%;
}
.centered {
  position: relative;
}
.msg {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <p class="msg">This is an important message</p>
</div>
```

Added background to show it's perfectly centered. It also works with any amount of text:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    message.innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, .centered {
  height: 100%;
}
.centered {
  position: relative;
}
.msg {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <p class="msg" id="message">This is an important message</p>
</div>
```

Added a timer to show.

Comment: Doesn't look fully vertically centered to me.

Comment: @ProEvilz Added `box-sizing` and background for a visual cue. Check now.

Comment: @ProEvilz that's just the *user agent* `margin` declared on the `p` tag, easily rectified by normalizing it with custom style.

Comment: Still the same. I'm using Chrome and 44% top value seems more accurate.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks. Let me try something.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError You are right. `margin:0;` fixes the issue. Perhaps OP(for answer) should include your tip in his answer?

Comment: Guys, I forgot to add reset.

Comment: @ProEvilz Go comment on the other answer as well... :)